# A slight modification to the recursion theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I always come across this version of the recursion theorem that is frequently used without justification:

> Given a function $g:A\longrightarrow A$ there exists exactly one funcion such that,
>
> 1. $f(0)=a_{0}, f(1)=a_{1},...,f(k)=a_{k}$
> 2. $f(n+k)=g(f(n))$

I guess of course that the original proof of the standard recursion theorem, meaning by using only the conditions $f(0)=a_{0}$ and $f(n+1)=g(f(n))$ would also work in this case. So my question is if it's possible to deduce this theorem not writing the proof again but supposing the standard theorem as proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

$$G:A^k\to A^k:\langle a_1,\dots,a_k\rangle\mapsto \langle g(a_1),\dots,g(a_k)\rangle$$

and use the ordinary result to define $F$ so that

1. $F(0)=\langle a_0,\dots,a_{k-1}\rangle$ and
2. $F(n+1)=G(F(n))$.

From $F$ you can easily extract $f$:

$$\begin{align*}
F(1)&=\langle g(a_0),\dots,g(a_{k-1})\rangle=\langle f(k),\dots,f(2k-1)\rangle\;,\\
F(2)&=\langle g(f(k)),\dots,g(f(2k-1))\rangle=\langle f(2k),\dots,f(3k-1)\rangle\;,
\end{align*}$$

and so on.